# Add Google Font to <head> in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, google-font-api, google-search-appliance

I'm using Google Search Appliance to filter search results & the page is written in XSLT. I'd like to link to Google fonts in the `<head>` but have not been able to manage.

HTML:

```
<head>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
```

XSL I've tried:

```
<xsl:template name="addOpenSansStart">
  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;head&gt;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:element name="link">
    <xsl:attribute name="href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600'">href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600'</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="rel='stylesheet'">rel='stylesheet'</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="type='text/css'">type='text/css'</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="addOpenSansEnd">
  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/head&gt;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:text>
  </xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

Also:

```
<xsl:template name="addOpenSansStart">
  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;head&gt;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' /&gt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="addOpenSansEnd">
  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/head&gt;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:text>
  </xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

Both gave me ***ERRORS*** The element type "link" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "`</link>`".

Comment: Did you try to generate <link....[same stuff here]  /> (i.e. closing the link tag)? Should work

Comment: The error message for the 1st block of code is:
***ERRORS*** Line 3738: Attribute name {href='https://fonts.googleapis...} is not a valid QName Line 3739: Attribute name {rel='stylesheet'} is not a valid QName Line 3740: Attribute name {type='text/css'} is not a valid QName ***WARNINGS*** Line 6: Running an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet with an XSLT 2.0 processor Line 2261: A variable with no following sibling instructions has no effect

Comment: I realized that I'd had the <link href=..> HTML posted below my XSL code for reference that was generating that 1st error.

Comment: I was formatting my code based on another XSL template & I now see that it's being called in different parts of the document. I don't know where to call my addOpenSansStart template so I ended up adding my <link... /> after `<meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW"/>` which I know is being pulled into the head & it's working now. Thanks for your replies!

Answer (score 2):

You'll be happy to learn that you can simply include the literal markup to be generated:

```
<xsl:template name="addOpenSansStart">
  <head>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600' 
          rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
  </head>
  <!-- the rest of your template -->
</xsl:template>
```

Should you ever actually need to use `xsl:element` and `xsl:attribute`, realize that the `name` attribute should not include the value of the attribute too:

```
<xsl:template name="addOpenSansStart">
  <head>
    <xsl:element name="link">
      <xsl:attribute name="href">https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="rel">stylesheet</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="type">text/css</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
  </head>
  <!-- the rest of your template -->
</xsl:template>
```

Either way should work for you.

Comment: I'm not sure what a typical Google Search Appliance xslt document looks like but the one I'm customizing is all over the place. The code isn't formatted from top to bottom the way I'm used to seeing it in HTML documents. But I'll keep this in mind if I'm ever working with a vanilla document. Thanks!